# How do I display images in a Windows Forms Application without knowing the number of images that need to be displayed?

Tags: c#, winforms

This might be a bit of a dumb question because I may be approaching the problem completely backwards, but I'm trying to display a set of images in a Windows Forms Application. The images are fetched from an API and obtaining their URLs is not a problem. The problem I'm having is actually displaying them in a table or a set of pictureboxes depending on how many images I download. The dimensions for all of the images are the same, I just need a way of displaying them.

Pictureboxes are easy enough, `pictureBox1.Load(Image_URL);` but the problem comes in when I need to create more pictureboxes depending on the number of images that I actually need to download.

Is there some other way to display images without knowing how many images I need to display?
Do I need to dynamically create pictureboxes and display each URL separately? I'm completely stumped on this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think easiest way to dynamically create pictureboxes is [DataRepeater](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488279.aspx) which you can find under *Visual Basic PowerPacks* node in toolbox. Here is sample of using it for images displaying: [DataRepeater Control for Windows Forms](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsdata/archive/2009/08/12/datarepeater-control-for-windows-forms.aspx)

Here is sample with displaying images from your local folder. Place DataRepeater control on your form. Then place PictureBox and Label on DataRepeater which you just added:

```
string path = @"D:\";
var query = from f in Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.jpg")
            select new { Path = f, FileName = Path.GetFileName(f) };

var files = query.ToList();
pictureBox1.DataBindings.Add("ImageLocation", files, "Path");
label1.DataBindings.Add("Text", files, "FileName");
dataRepeater1.ItemHeaderVisible = false; // to hide headers
dataRepeater1.DataSource = files;
```

That's it. All found images will be displayed.

Comment: So you're adding a list of files and the pictureBox knows to display them as pictures? My problem would be that I'm saving the images into a List Image<>. I'm trying to do this without saving image files, if possible.

Comment: Also, when I do download the files, I get this error:

    Additional information: This causes two bindings in the collection to bind to the same property.

Comment: @pendo324 make sure you call `ToList()` before provide bindings

Comment: @lazyberezovsky Thanks a lot for your help! Now to make a cool looking grid.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options here depending on your requirements.

**Option 1:**
if you have to show some extra information along with your pictures than you may consider using listview/gridview.

**Option 2:**
Otherwise you can create picture boxes dynamically and assign them the url.

Answer (score 0):

My advice is, you can simply take DataGridView with a DataGridViewImageColumn and you can add  rows whatever you want